# Xcode downloads client crash reports for [CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayLink]

Tags: cocoa, appkit

Xcode contains several crash reports downloaded from users of my app. Thread 0 apparently crashes at `[CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayLink]`, but there's not a single stacktrace line that contains code within my app, so I have no idea what this means or how to reproduce it.

What could cause such a crash?

```
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501
...
OS Version:            macOS 14.0 (23A344)
...
Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 4 Illegal instruction: 4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [1920]

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   AppKit                          0x00007ff81c3730c1 -[NSApplication _crashOnException:] + 289 (NSApplication.m:7290)
1   AppKit                          0x00007ff81c175ea5 __62+[CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayLink]_block_invoke + 853 (NSCATransaction.m:98)
2   AppKit                          0x00007ff81cc43339 ___NSRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler_block_invoke + 41 (AppKit_Internal.h:760)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00007ff818a13836 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23 (CFRunLoop.c:1789)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00007ff818a1375a __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 493 (CFRunLoop.c:1902)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00007ff818a12cdc __CFRunLoopRun + 850 (CFRunLoop.c:2946)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00007ff818a12372 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   HIToolbox                       0x00007ff82327e9d9 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292 (EventLoop.c:455)
8   HIToolbox                       0x00007ff82327e616 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 201 (EventBlocking.c:311)
9   HIToolbox                       0x00007ff82327e531 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 66 (EventBlocking.c:171)
10  AppKit                          0x00007ff81c01a0c5 _DPSNextEvent + 880 (CGDPSReplacement.m:806)
11  AppKit                          0x00007ff81c90b150 -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1304 (appEventRouting.m:410)
12  AppKit                          0x00007ff81c00b63a -[NSApplication run] + 603 (NSApplication.m:3488)
13  AppKit                          0x00007ff81bfdf670 NSApplicationMain + 816 (NSApplication.m:10105)
14  MyApp                           0x0000000100627071 main + 129 (main.swift:12)
15  dyld                            0x00007ff8185b03a6 start + 1942 (dyldMain.cpp:1269)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007ff8188f9a2e mach_msg2_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007ff818907e4a mach_msg2_internal + 84 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007ff818900b6e mach_msg_overwrite + 653 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007ff8188f9d1f mach_msg + 19 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00007ff818a14475 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 143 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00007ff818a12ee5 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00007ff818a12372 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   AppKit                          0x00007ff81c1773e0 _NSEventThread + 122 (NSEvent.m:5493)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007ff818939202 _pthread_start + 99 (pthread.c:904)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007ff818934bab thread_start + 15
```

Comment: What is in that block?

Comment: What block do you mean?

Comment: Your CFRunLoop observer callback.

Comment: I didn't set up any run loop observer, in case you're referring to `__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__`. I think that if I did, the stacktrace would show the line of code where the observer was registered, which it doesn't. The only line referring to my code is `main.swift:12`, which reads `_ = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)`.

Comment: Please, let us know if you found something. Got a similar xccrashpoint.

Comment: Sadly, I still have no idea.